# Treat project file as npm module

Tags: module, npm

Is there a way using npm to treat a file in the project as a node-module without linking it and it having it's own package.json?

Ideally I could just have a sub-module definition within my main app package.json and be able to install things to a specific module that way.

Here's an example

```
/app
  /index.js
  /file.js
  /action.js
```

What I'd like

```
npm set-as-module ./action.js "action"
```

Then within any file in my project I can call

```
var action = require("action")
```

Then when I want to install specific dependancies for action I could do this

```
npm install underscore --save --sub=action
```

This this kind of feature exist within NPM? Anything close to it?

This would offer the following perks

- Easy to branch out or publish into full module
- ability to require with module string instead of path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created something to do this

https://github.com/reggi/npm-link-file

```
npm install npm-link-file -g
npm-link-file ./action.js "action"
```

It does not handle linked dependancies.